# Payment Gateway Solution for Mobile Payments

Tags: collaboration

I am looking for a company who has the skills to implement the following solution for a Government/National carrier deployment:

- The carrier has the infrastructure to move the transactions and they accept a bulk payments from TTCL for example,
- That transaction has to be verified against the National ID database,
- All the above have to pass through a central point that handles it (that is what they need and we will need to fulfil).
- Payroll division from TTCL has an App/portal or something that says “payroll online” or something like that
- They fill out the info and save the batch, or if its regular get a normal batch and presses go
- That batch gets sent to our “gateway box/solution”, it references the payroll against the payee’s ID number and uses some form of validation (name etc)
- It then tags that name to the National ID eWallet and approves the transaction,
- That then comes back to our gateway which then transmits the credit using MPESA to the eWallet endpoint devices (where they can swipe their national ID/ATM etc. AND their mobile money account
- So if they spend it with the phone, the transaction interfaces with the mobile wallet…again though our gateway/platform etc

Please come back and let me know whether this is more in line with your abilities.

If not if you know of anyone who can help I would be very grateful.

Many thanks